# AWS Elastic search : Search should be performed on all combination with given query

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, dsl, querydsl

I'm working on AWS Elastic Search. I've come across one situation in my project where in my reports i have to search keywords like "corona virus".

But result should come with containing keywords like "Corona virus" and "corona" and "virus" and "coronavirus".

Please guide me how i should build my query DSL.

Note: Working on PHP language.

Appreciate your help.

//Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [shingle token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html)

> A token filter of type shingle that constructs shingles (token
>   n-grams) from a token stream. In other words, it creates combinations
>   of tokens as a single token. For example, the sentence "please divide
>   this sentence into shingles" might be tokenized into shingles "please
>   divide", "divide this", "this sentence", "sentence into", and "into
>   shingles".

Mapping

```
PUT index91
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "shingle_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "shingle_filter": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "max_shingle_size": 3,
          "output_unigrams": true,
           "token_separator": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
POST index91/_doc
{
  "title":"corona virus"
}
```

Query:

```
GET index91/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "coronavirus"
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index91",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gNmUZHEBrJsHVOidaoU_",
        "_score" : 0.9438393,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "corona virus"
        }
      }
```

It will also work for "corona", "corona virus","virus"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But im not understanding here where i should put my seasrch query as "corona virus" in shingles.  Can you please put this search query words in below PUT query DSL,

Comment: Shingle is just a analyser (while indexing) . Specifying analyzer is part of mapping. For search you just need to use match query

Comment: If you will follow the answer, you will see I have assigned an analyzer using shingles to a field while creating index. Then queried it using simple match query. By default the analyzer used is "standard" which splits text based on space which cannot be used for your issue hence a different way of creating tokens is needed( so Shingles)

Comment: Thanks @jaspreet for you help.